# How to resample 1 minute data to 10 minute data?

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv('D:\\Ayush\\Data\\Bank nifty Data\\Testing.csv')

file['Date_time'] = file['Date/Time'] + ' ' + file['Time']
file['Date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(file['Date_time'])
file.drop(columns=['Date/Time','Time'],inplace=True)
file['Date'] = file['Date_time'].dt.date
file['Date_time'].set_index(inplace=True)

ohlc_dict = {
            'open':'first',
            'high':'max',
            'low':'min',
            'close':'last',
            'volume':'sum'
            }
a = file.resample('10min',how=ohlc_dict)
```

The above is the complete code. I have gone through other posts too regarding resampling, but I just could not get through it.
After I run this code, I get an error:

```
TypeError: resample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'how'
```

I changed this to the code

```
file.resample('10min').apply(ohlc_dict)
```

now I am getting this error

```
SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported
```

Comment: what's `file`? what type is it?

Comment: Its a simple OHLC and volume data ( one minute ) which is in csv format

Comment: Please show your full code and an example file so we can reproduce it

Comment: Did you check the [`resample` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)? There is no argument `how` to this method...

Comment: how do I specify the method on the basis of which resample has to be done ?

Comment: Can you try `file.resample('10min').agg(ohlc_dict)` ?

Comment: Still i am getting SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: pandas                1.0.1
pandas-datareader     0.8.1

Comment: tested under `pandas 1.0.1 ` and  `file.resample('10min').agg(ohlc_dict)` and working nice  for me.

Comment: got it. It made some silly mistake.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
file.high.resample('10min').max()
```

I will suggest you to do the resample 1 by 1.

https://benalexkeen.com/resampling-time-series-data-with-pandas/

Comment: What do I mentioned under close, where I need the last value ?

Comment: .last() is one of supported method in resample in panda

Answer (score 1):

following code can be used to resample '1min' data to '10min' data :-

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['open'] = file.open.resample('10min').first()
df['high'] = file.high.resample('10min').max()
df['low'] = file.low.resample('10min').min()
df['close'] = file.close.resample('10min').last()
```

Comment: It is the most straightforward solution. And in case volume is needed too: `df['vol'] = file.vol.resample('5T').sum()`